# PHP date.timezone no value

Tags: php, timezone

I just create new server on windows OS x64 with.

```
httpd-2.4.9-win64-VC11
php-5.5.14-Win32-VC11-x64
MySql Server
```

I go into `php.ini` Uncomment and add this:

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"
```

I make and see in `phpinfo.php` and found my `date.timezone` with `no value` in local and master value.

As below

> date/time support enabled "Olson" Timezone Database Version   2014.3
>   Timezone Database internal Default timezone   UTC
>
> Directive Local Value Master Value
>   date.default_latitude 31.7667 31.7667
>   date.default_longitude    35.2333 35.2333
>   date.sunrise_zenith   90.583333   90.583333
>   date.sunset_zenith    90.583333   90.583333 date.timezone **no value  no value**

And there are also appear `error message` on same page (phpinfo.php) as below:

```
Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in J:\WebDocs\gad\phpinfo.php on line 2

Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in J:\WebDocs\gad\phpinfo.php on line 2
```

Here is my current `php.ini`

http://codepad.org/u2xHBP8a

Is this related to php.ini module? and what is the best way to solve this.

Comment: did you restart apache? did you edit correct php.ini?

Comment: @Lashane yes I restart apache and same happen.

Comment: Ensure you are editing the correct php.ini. Some systems have a separate one for CLI and Apache. Run phpinfo() in a web file and the top section will give the path to the parsed ini file.

Comment: @KonrNess There is only one php.ini in folder. If you read carefully my post you will see php-5.5.14-Win32-VC11-x64 and you already know what files and folder contains in this versions.

Comment: Please make sure that php.ini you have edited is the one used by the apache. In your phpinfo() there is a line in the header about 'loaded PHP configuration' or smth like that, which contains the path to php.ini.

Comment: I found solution on this, because lack of sleep I add PHPIniDir "H:/PHP" this is wrong, it should be PHPIniDir "J:/PHP"

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");` ?

Comment: I resolved removing the comment in the file php.ini. Just remove the ';' before date.timezone!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is *quick solution* I found this morning,

In `httpd.conf` line `PHPIniDir`

```
"H:/PHP"
```

Should be this way

```
"J:/PHP"
```

Comment: So, you were loading wrong php.ini file... because you put wrong phpinidir in the httpd.conf. Always check for it first, if you are having trouble with configuration - open phpinfo and see which file is loaded.

Comment: @Toly noted, guru. +2.

Answer (score -1):

US/Central is not a valid timezone for PHP.

The valid American timezones are here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

For Central time use America/Chicago instead.

Comment: I have try before and this is not the current solution.

Comment: Yes, it is *valid*, it's just not recommended.  [Reference here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php).